# Implement floating images

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images

I've seen some questions that contain screenshots from smartphones (portrait oriented) that look ugly especially in the middle of the post (usually that means that one has to scroll until they see the rest of the post). Sometimes I see such images attached via a link which is partially justified by the fact that they will make the question look ugly if attached as images.

So, is there a possibility to make an image float to the right? (**update**: ok, they say it's not possible for the moment, see the answers) Consider this as a feature request. I'm not totally sure what the `!` part does in the syntax

```
[![image description][1]][1]
```

but probably floating can be introduced via

```
[>[image description][1]][1]
```

(to the right) or

```
[<[image description][1]][1]
```

(to the left).

In fact, the syntax is not very important (a button on the insert image form + any syntax would do).

Comment: Sounds very similar to an old [CommonMark discussion](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/floating-images/266/27)

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm somewhat confused. So the issue is there's no such feature in markdown? And as long as it's true, no one will implement this?

Comment: Not exactly; there are flavors of Markdown that do support it. Note that [this has been requested before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99573/can-we-get-a-way-to-wrap-text-around-images), but there's concern it would be abused / would break mobile devices / would cause demons to fly out of your nose.

Comment: @Shog9 I preemptively exorcised my nose, am I safe?